# CHEF, how do you replace node.set/node.save in chef solo?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

How do you replace `node.set`/`node.save` in chef solo?

I am using node.set/node.save in this example to execute certain commands on first run-> http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_resources_first_run.html

But on chef-solo there is no `node.set`/`node.save`.  So what replaces that? How to store persistent flags in this example in chef solo?

Comment: You should try to avoid them with chef-solo (by design), and maybe ask/allow the user to persist or provide the values from the beginning on.

Comment: Agreed that is one of the main purposes of having a chef server, to store node state between chef runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no persistence in Chef Solo (it's one of the major drawbacks). You should do something like this:

```
node.save unless Chef::Config[:solo]
```

You can still call `node.set` safely, but that data is only persisted in the run.

You may also want to look into something like [Chef Zero](https://github.com/opscode/chef-zero) or [Knife Solo](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo).